# Pycharm External tools relative to Virtual Environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, pycharm, pylint

Using the PyCharm IDE, when setting up an external tool, how can you set up the external tools with a path relative to use the current virtual env defaults.?

An example being pylint - where I'd want the virtual env version and not the system one to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's *JDKPath* macro you can use which points to the executable of the interpreter set for a project. You can combine this with the fact that many tools can be run by directly running their module(s) using the `-m` option of interpreter. Also there's issue [PY-2734 New useful macros in external tools](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-2734) everyone can vote on.

Comment: Ah - so close. I am using the "pylint-pycharm" tool which enhances pylint with pycharm clickable links - so it doesn't currently work with "-m" (it could perhaps be modified to do so though..)

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. Other than the detail I added - it sounds correct.

Comment: @DannyStaple: "pylint-pycharm" tool? Google can't find that. Is it ours?

Comment: I got it from here - my first thread in google: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206590125-Use-Pylint-from-inside-PyCharm - https://github.com/perses76/pylint-pycharm

Answer (score 17):

Not sure about older versions, but in PyCharm 5 one can use `$PyInterpreterDirectory$` macro. It's exactly that we want

Answer (score 0):

just found your post while looking for documentation about the "variables" that could bew used when setting parameters for external tools.

No documentation but you can see a list of all the available stuff after pressing thE "INSERT MACRO" button in the Edit Tool dialog.

I don't see any reference to the interpreter path there but I usually use the virtualenv as my project path. If you are doing that too you could infer the python interpreter path from there.

Answer (score 0):

In Tool Settings, set `Program:` to `$PyInterpreterDirectory$/pylint`